# How can I get my Dell C1760nw Printer to work with Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, hardware

Ubuntu doesn't recignize this model of printer automatically. How can I get it to work correctly in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 14.04 (and earlier versions):

**If you have a 64-bit system,** copy and paste this into the Terminal (open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2:i386
```

**If you have a 32-bit system,** ignore that terminal command and proceed.

Download the [Ubuntu .deb drivers from Xerox](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6000/file-redirect/engb.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en_GB&contentId=116065) for their Phaser 6000 model. It comes packaged in a .zip file. (The Dell C1760nw is a "repackaged" version of this model, which means that the core printing device works the same as a Xerox Phaser 6000 because it came from the same factory, but it is assembled and sold to retailers by Dell instead of Xerox.)

You will need to save this .zip file, and extract its contents with a right-click if you are looking at it in the File Manager. A folder will be extracted, and therein will be a .deb package file. You should double-click this to open it.

You may encounter a window saying that the package is of "bad quality". You can safely ignore this; it's coming up because of an incorrectly entered variable that declares the creator of the file.

Then, install the printer. *If you are prompted to choose a printer manufacturer and model, enter it as a Xerox 6000b.* It works!

Note that all of these steps are still required to use the printer over the network.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in Ubuntu 12.04.5 64bit. Thank you tons!

Answer (score 4):

Two more steps were required for mine:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

and

```
sudo service cups restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't comment so post an answer as of Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.10.

@Richard's answer is not sufficient for me and @user590496's trick is further needed. The credits go to @Richard and @user590496 but I also summarize the steps:

1. Install the internet print protocol:

   ```
   sudo apt install libcupsimage2:i386
   ```
2. Install the C++, compression, and ncurses libraries (the 32bit versions worked for my 64bit system):

   ```
   sudo apt install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5
   ```
3. Download and install [Xerox Phaser 6000 driver](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6000/file-download/engb.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en_GB&contentId=116065&from=downloads&viewArchived=false)
4. Setup the printer from System Settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me,

> sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5

was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from here: http://codefucius.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/getting-dell-c1760nw-color-printer-up.html

"To get this working on Ubuntu 64bit I had to follow the instructions about installing the .deb file but I also had to install some extra i386 libraries:

sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2:i386
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386

http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6000/downloads/engb.html?operatingSystem=linux

Open the .deb file with the Ubuntu Software Center when prompted to do so, or save it and double-click it in the file manager."